# Load more hide previous content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code using jquery, as I do when to display 4 new content it hid the previous 4 and when it reaches the end back to the beginning. Like a carousel.

Currently when you click on load more it keeps all the contents ready, current and previous.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

div {
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>Content</div>
<div>Content 1</div>
<div>Content 2</div>
<div>Content 3</div>
<div>Content 4</div>

<div>Content 5</div>
<div>Content 6</div>
<div>Content 7</div>
<div>Content 8</div>
<div>Content 9</div>
<div>Content 10</div>



<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});



</script>
</body>
</htmL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think a better way to do this is to make the sets and then work with these sets ...
i have make some changes to give you idea...
checkout and let me know that is this the same that you want ?

```js
$(function() {


  $(".set").first().show();

  $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".set:visible").slideUp();
    $(".set:visible").next().slideDown();


    if ($(".set:visible").length == 1) {
      $(".set:visible").slideUp();
      $(".set").first().slideDown();
    }


    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  //display:none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.set {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="set">
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
    <div>Content 4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="set">
    <div>Content 5</div>
    <div>Content 6</div>
    <div>Content 7</div>
    <div>Content 8</div>
  </div>

  <div class="set">
    <div>Content 9</div>
    <div>Content 10</div>
    <div>Content 11</div>
    <div>Content 12</div>
  </div>



  <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

</body>

</htmL>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you'll have to do is at every div content section you'll have to have a button in that div container that will trigger a special event.

you should go about this with something like:

```
  <div id="view1"> <h1>what ever your content is.<h1>
                  <p> then lets put a button below this
           It could be housed in a paragraph, div or table container 
           how ever you want</p>
           <p align="center"> <button id="hide1">Next </button> </p>

   </div>
```

your java would look like this for each button view:

```
     <script>



      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hide1").click(function(){
          $("#view1").hide();
          $("#view3").hide(); */ and list all the div you want to keep hidden
          $("#view4").hide();
       $("#view5").hide();
        $("#view6").hide()    
          $("#view2").show();
         });

            });




            </script>
```

then you'll need a script section to define your page, so it will execute on page load

```
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#view2").hide();
         $("#view3").hide();   
        $("#view4").hide();
       $("#view5").hide();
        $("#view6").hide();

      });
       </script>
```

of course you can combine the sets and put the page load code and your buttons click functions in the same document ready function to make the code run faster, but I decided to separate the two so I could be explain it better.