# Load more and hide previous data without pagination in php part?

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

Is it possible to load more content and hide previous content with jquery instead of pagination in php part ?

Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44358610/19168006)

```
$(function() {
  $(".set").first().show();
  $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".set:visible").slideUp();
    $(".set:visible").next().slideDown();
    if ($(".set:visible").length == 1) {
      $(".set:visible").slideUp();
      $(".set").first().slideDown();
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

But in that example contents are in seperate divs.

I searched on google and in here but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: why can't you use separate div ? and hide previous div each time your loading new data?

Comment: @skytorner I do use divs, but in that example content divs are limited to 1, each class named set has 5 posts in it so it displays 1 div actulay.  when we do foreach it loads all contents with set div, and shows only one content each time, in real we need to access in set divs and set a limitation on it. example: load 10 each time.

Comment: I have created a one fiddle demo for you if this will work for you then please let me know, i will add it in comment. Because you get an idea exactly what you want. If my code is not solving your doubt then sorry for that.
Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/9zv186p5/41/

Comment: @RBC Tried it works like a charm thanks, add as an answer please. can we make it slower like fadeIn and out slow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DLK I add code asd below for reference of your question, please look into it, might it will help logically.

```js
  $(function () {
      $(".nextContent").slice(0, 2).show();
            let $click = 0;
      $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
            $click++;
          $(".nextContent").slice(0, $click*2).hide();
          e.preventDefault();          
          $(".nextContent:hidden").slice($click*2, $click*2+2).slideDown();
          if ($(".nextContent:hidden").length == 0) {
              $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
              $('#loadmore').replaceWith("<p class='p'>No More</p>");
          }
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
          }, 1500);
      });
  });
```

```css
.nextContent {
  display:none;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
#loadMore {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #33739E;
    color: #fff;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #33739E;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="nextContent">Content1</div>
<div class="nextContent">Content2</div>
<div class="nextContent">Content3</div>
<div class="nextContent">Content4</div>
<div class="nextContent">Content5</div>
<div class="nextContent">Content6</div>
<div class="nextContent">Content7</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
</html>
```

Thanks:)

Comment: its more than perfect with `.slideDown("slow")` .lol Thank you so much, you saved me creating pagination :)